# How to extend class defined in one scala file from another scala file

Tags: java, scala

Here is my first scala file, named Node.scala

```
class Node extends NodeType
{
   object Node  {
   val E = new Node(NodeType.E)

}
```

Here is my NodeType.scala

```
class NodeType extends Enumeration {
  val PROGRAM = new NodeType()
  val DECLARATIONS = new NodeType()
  val DECLARATION = new NodeType()
  val TYPE = new NodeType()
  val STATEMENTSEQUENCE = new NodeType()
  val STATEMENT = new NodeType()
  val ASSIGNMENT = new NodeType()
  val IFSTATEMENT = new NodeType()
  val WHILESTATEMENT = new NodeType()
  val WRITEINT = new NodeType()
  val ELSECLAUSE = new NodeType()
  val EXPRESSION = new NodeType()
  val SIMPLEEXPRESSION = new NodeType()
  val TERM = new NodeType()
  val FACTOR = new NodeType()
  val E = new NodeType()
  class NodeType extends Val
  implicit def convertValue(v: Value): NodeType = v.asInstanceOf[NodeType]
}
```

I am getting error at NodeType and when the cursor is highlighted it says 
**not found type NodeType**

Comment: How are you compiling your classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val E = new Node(NodeType.E)
```

This is trying to access a companion object called NodeType and get its field E.

What you defined as NodeType is not a companion object, it is a class. Think of companion objects like the static portion of a class in Java-terms. You're trying to access the "static" portion of NodeType which doesn't exist because a companion object for NodeType has not been defined.

Furthermore, why are you trying to construct a new Node with an argument? Your node class takes 0 parameters.

Perhaps you could try to explain to us what you are trying to model.